# Unable to enroll Windows workstation in enterprise CA - DNS_ERROR_NAME_DOES_NOT_EXIST

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

I have a single machine, out of hundreds, that will not pull a certificate from our enterprise CA when trying to enroll it.

The CA shows a failed request with error: `DNS name does not exist. 0x800725f2 (WIN32: 9714 DNS_ERROR_NAME_DOES_NOT_EXIT)`

The computer event log shows the same entry.

I cannot figure out for the life of me what is different about this machine. I have checked or performed the following items:

1. Checked that the machine has a DNS name in AD. In the general tab it has it's FQDN in the `DNS name` section, and under the attribute editor the `dNSHostName` attribute matches it's FQDN.
2. Reset permissions on the computer object in AD.
3. Deleted the local, existing certificate from the machine.
4. Tried a different certificate template on the CA. Now two errors are generated (one for each template).
5. Confirmed that both the forward and reverse DNS records in AD are accurate (long shot there).
6. Verified the machine's name on the host, matches that in AD.

The CA template is configured to build the certificate's subject name/and alternate subject name from AD:

[image]

The best understanding I have of this problem is that the CA is querying AD for information about the computer and either it is missing or it does not have permission to view it. If that is the case, I cannot find where the problem is or what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that `ipconfig /all` showed that the `Primary DNS Suffix` for the machine was blank.

I went ahead and set the machine's primary DNS suffix to match our windows AD domain name and the problem was resolved.

To change the machine's primary DNS suffix, navigate to System Settings -> Computer Name/Domain or Workgroup -> Change. Click 'More' in the "Computer Name/Domain Changes" window, and modify the computer's Primary DNS suffix. It should match the name of the domain.

[image]

This is the first time I realized that you can join an AD domain and actually modify the primary dns suffix to something other than the AD domain name.